# Can a medial he with shva end a syllable?

Tags: grammar-dikduk

In the word וַיִּתְמַהְמָהּ in Genesis 19:16, does the first ה end a syllable so the shva under it is a shva nach and consequently the ה itself is also silent, so the word is pronounced vayitmamahhhhh, or does it begin the fourth syllable and the shva is a shva na, so the word is pronounced vayitmahemahhhhh?

Answer (score 4):

Both letters ה in that word are pronounced the same. They both end syllables beginning with מ.

Shva nach on consonants at the end of a word is conventionally omitted from writing, so in the relatively unusual case where a letter which usually just marks a vowel is intended as a consonant, [a dot is included in that letter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45220/759) to indicate its '[harder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/114187/759)' status. Only a letter without any vowels on it is [entirely silent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/115575/759) since it serves itself as a [vowel for the previous consonant](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89370/759).

Comment: In other words, neither option presented in the question is correct, and the word is pronounced (according to the OP’s transliteration system) ‘vayitmahhhhhmahhhhh’.