Is there a glottal stop when pronouncing ?וְלָראוּבֵנִי
In the word וְלָראוּבֵנִי (Devarim 3:16):
Is the Aleph totally silent, or does it go with the vowel to produce a glottal stop after the Reish?
Rabbi Jeremy Wieder's recording doesn't seem to do a glottal stop? Or is it just barely there?

The person who taught me that parsha (for my Bar Mitzvah) taught me with a completely silent Alef. Ve-la-Ru-ve-ni. If that counts for anything.

Why should there be when alef is a silent letter?

If the alef were to be pronounced with the shuruk vowel, the reish would have to have its own vowel. We'd have seen וְלָרְאוּבֵנִי. Compare עֵינַ֥יִם לָ֝הֶ֗ם וְלֹ֣א יִרְאֽוּ with יְר֣אוּ אֶת־יְהוָ֣ה קְדֹשָׁ֑יו . See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89370/759 and (yesterday's haftara) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/115575/759

@Dude Alef is not a silent letter any more than Hei Vav or Yud is. All have sounds, but are sometimes silent when just marking a vowel.
